# Proving SAT is in L

Tags: satisfiability, np, space-complexity

How to prove that SAT is in L if and only if NP=L? I know that reducing SAT in cook-levin theorem is computable in deterministic linear space . How to do it in log space? Any reference will also help.

Comment: Schaefer in his paper [THE COMPLEXITY OF SATISFIABILITY PROBLEMS](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/lieber/courses/csg260/f06/materials/papers/max-sat/p216-schaefer.pdf) stated (unfortunately without a proof), that every NP problem is log-space reducible to 3-SAT.  If it's true then if SAT is in L then every NP problem is in L, so it may be good idea to find a proof of that.

Comment: The usual proof of the Cook–Levin theorem can be implemented in logspace. You don't have to do anything special.